# What is the name of this formula??

Tags: average, means, system-identification, python

Let `formula_a = lambda array: sum(array) / len(array)`. We may rename this formula to be `average` or `mean` if so desired. Let `formula_b = lambda array: reduce(mul, array) ** (1 / len(array))`. What is the name of this second formula?

Comment: Google "geometric mean" now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: 
If the array is called $a$ and $N = \text{len}(a)$, then the code expresses the formula

$$\left(\prod_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i\right)^{1/N}$$

Or equivalently

$$\sqrt[N]{\prod_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i}$$

**Extended hint**: The formula is known as the *geometric mean* of a series of values (i.e. the array). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean))

Comment: Thanks! I am a programmer, not a mathematician. You answered in a comment. Would you mind including the name in your answer as well?

Comment: Included :). If you don't get something about the code, you can ask as well, but I guess you just didn't know this particular formula.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how to type mathematical formulas on here. That is why it was written in Python instead. I had been thinking of a variation on the arithmetic mean and independently and internally "invented" a calculation that you identified as the geometric mean. Thanks for your help!